# Swift UI - ReferencerTester.swift File. Receiving Error while trying to append to an array

Tags: swift, xcode, testing, swiftui, swift-class

I am trying to add and instance of Class Wave to my instance of class WaveList

I don't know why I am unable to simply append this within my Test File.

My Classes look like this:

```
class Wave {
var name: String
var country: String
var type: String
var left: String
var right: String
var image: String

init(name: String, country: String, type: String, left: String, right: String, image: String){
    self.name = name
    self.country = country
    self.type = type
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.image = image
}


class WaveList{
var waves: [Wave] = []

func addWave(wave: Wave){
    self.waves.append(wave)
}
```

Thank You

[image: Test File]

Comment: Remove Wave.swift file from ReferencerTests target.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked, would you mind explaining why?

Comment: See details in posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove *Wave.swift* file from *ReferencerTests* target, as you already have it in context by importing *Referencer* as testable.

> Thanks a lot, this worked, would you mind explaining why?

When you included *Wave.swift* in *ReferencerTests* the type `Wave` become present in `ReferencerTests` module namespace, so `ReferencerTests.Wave` resolved by priority, but interface imported via *@testable* expected original, ie `Referencer.Wave`, so there is conflict and compiler reports you about this.